# How can I use flatbuffers parse json in C++?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I have some protocol file, but they don't have root type. So I can't use flatc to parse json. When I look up for the docs, I find a few methods.For example: `flatbuffes::Parse flatbuffers::Registry`.I don't know how to use them correctly,because I'm not very proficient in C++.Can anyone give me an example or detailed documentation.
A protocol file

```
namespace serial.proto.api.login;

table LoginReq {
    account:string; 
    passwd:string; 
    device:string;  
    token:string;
}

table LoginRsp {
    account:string; 
    passwd:string;  
    device:string; 
    token:string;
}

table LogoutReq {
    account:string;
}

table LogoutRsp {
    account:string;
}
```

My code:

```
auto json_file = R"({"account":"test","passwd":"test01","device":"test","token":"asdfasdfasdf"})";
    flatbuffers::Parser parser;
    parser.Parse(json_file);
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C++, you will love it here once you get over pointers and STL templates.

Before I answer your question you should look at [this](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/4403) discussion on the library repo .

You need to make sure the parser contains a schema, otherwise it wouldn't know where or how to generate the result.

You could do something like so:

```cpp
parser.Parse(schema.c_str())
```

where `schema` is the loaded schema

Hope this helps